# Highmaps support for zip5

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

Does Highmaps support displaying data based on zip5 codes? If so where can I get the JSON file for US with zip5 codes?
I have tried to look at the Highcharts/Highmaps documentation and the collection of the Maps in highmaps at http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/ but I couldn't find anything specific to zip5.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to create your own GeoJSON map for United States ZIP codes. Highcharts has a demo that mentions ZIP codes, which you might find informative:

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

Shapefiles based on ZIP codes can be found on the Census Bureau's page here:

https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html

I hope these resources help point you in the right direction.